# useCallback doesn't prevent unnecessary re-renders

Tags: reactjs

Custom hook - useBreadcrumbs:

```
const useBreadcrumbs = (arr: Crumb[] = [], crumbs: Function) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    crumbs(arr);
    return () => {
      crumbs([]);
    };
  }, [arr, crumbs]);
};
```

Using this hook inside Partners component:

```
useBreadcrumbs([{ title: 'Breadcrumb title', url: '/custom-page' }], crumbs);
```

Dashboard component:

```
const [breadcrumbs, setBreadcrumbs] = useState<Crumb[]>([]);
const handleCrumbs = useCallback((data: Crumb[]) => {
  setBreadcrumbs(data);
}, []);

return (
  <Partners crumbs={handleCrumbs} />
);
```

When a Partners component is mounted, i'm getting infinite loop with re-renders. I won't use `useEffect()` with empty deps, because it would cause exhaustive deps lint error. I'm preventing re-renders with `useCallback`. If i remove `arr` from `useEffect`:

```
useEffect(() => {
  crumbs(arr);
  return () => {
    crumbs([]);
  };
}, [crumbs]);
```

Then it doesn't loop infinitely, but i get an error:

```
ESLint: React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'arr'. Either include it or remove the dependency array.(react-hooks/exhaustive-deps)
```

How to avoid these loops in `useCallback`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create a brand new array there:

```
useBreadcrumbs([{ title: 'Breadcrumb title', url: '/custom-page' }], crumbs);
```

Which causes `useEffect`'s dependencies array to change in `useBreadcrumbs`, and it calls a function which updates your components and you have an infinite loop.

The solution is to use `useMemo` to preserve the  array over time, without creating a new one:

```
const arr = useMemo(() => [{ title: 'Breadcrumb title', url: '/custom-page' }], [])
useBreadcrumbs(arr, crumbs);
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks, with `useMemo` do i still need to use `useCallback`?

Comment: Yeah, sure, it might cause the same problem, and let `useBreadcrumbs` deps depend on both `[arr, crumbs]` :)

Comment: Is it common practice to use `useMemo` and `useCallback` in tandem? Also docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo recommend to write code as there was no `useMemo` hook.

Comment: In this particular case it's a must. And it's completely fine, as long as it gives you some sort of advantage or if you know it's useful to apply memoization in a specific case

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "recommend to write code as there was no useMemo hook"?

Comment: "Write your code so that it still works without useMemo — and then add it to optimize performance." They kinda plan to remove it in the future as i understood. Maybe my approach is wrong on how to pass breadcrumbs from individual page to a parent component?

Comment: No, it's about approach of writing code like that: 1) you write code without optimizations 2) then you optimize your code if need. So they're not planning to delete it. You could just create an object with like `{ 'page1': { title: '...', url: '...' } }`. And then access if anywhere, and it also has stable reference so it'll work without `useMemo`